# Customization of atreal.richfile.preview in plone

Tags: python, plone, zope

W.r.t Customization of atreal.richfile.preview in plone, for file preview, there is a template called viewlet.pt, it contains a TAL statement which displays the controls to activate/update, refresh and collapse the Actions menu:  . The full code snippet:

```
<dl class="richfile portlet"
    tal:condition="view/available"
    tal:attributes="id view/plugin_id"
    i18n:domain="atreal.richfile.preview">

    <dt tal:attributes="id string:${view/plugin_id}Header" class="rfheader portletHeader">
        <span class="portletTopLeft"></span>
        <!--tal:block tal:replace="structure view/controls" -->
        <span class="title" style="font-weight:bold"
            i18n:translate="">
            Preview 
        </span>

        <span class="portletTopRight"> <span>
    </dt>

   <dd tal:content="structure view/getPreview" >

        <!--Your specific code here-->        
        <IFRAME src="http://somesite.com" 
            tal:attributes="src string:${here/absolute_url}/rfpreview"
            ondragstart="false" onselectstart="false"
            width="100%" height="400" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"> </IFRAME>

        <!--End of specific code-->

    </dd>

</dl>
```

If I remove the `<tal:block tal:replace="structure view/controls" >`, I can view the doc, xls, odt file formats correctly. But for **pdf** files all the content is jumbled up. If I keep the above statement as it is, it opens another window when I click the action controls activate/update or refresh and is viewed correctly, BUT it downloads the doc xls and other files (which is not expected due to the hyperlink)

Also note after changing the default `<dd>` attributes to  `<dd tal:content="structure view/getPreview">` allows to view the pdf files without the background image.

If the statement  is left as it is, a new window is opened where there are icons to zoom, print, save as. I wish to disable these in this window.

Also I wish to prevent copy_paste from this new window.(The disabling copy paste I can do with javascript in the viewlet) but it doesn't happen in the new window.I am unable to detect the template for this new window.

**Main aim is to prevent any kind of copy/paste/download of any file from the plone site but should allow file preview.**

Can anybody guide correctly as to the exact location in ZMI and how to customize it?
Plone 4.1

Answer (score 0):

The alternate way to resolve this problem is given by customising  the template and available at [How to set TAL condition to check the file type and accordingly render the template in Plone 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260688/how-to-set-tal-condition-to-check-the-file-type-and-accordingly-render-the-templ/12261071#12261071)