# How to set TAL condition to check the file type and accordingly render the template in Plone 4.1

Tags: python, plone, zope, template-tal, zpt

How to use the tal condition to check the file type and render the template in Plone 4.1

My file preview template rendering depends upon the file extension. If file extension is 'pdf', I wish to use something like this:(just started working with TAL, TALES, METAL)

```
<tal:define="file_nm global string:${here/absolute_url}"
<tal:condition="file_nm.slice[-3:] = 'pdf'">

    <embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plug-in" tal:attributes="src string:${here/absolute_url}#" 
         draggable="false" onselectstart="false"  />
```

else use :(for files other than 'pdf')

```
<IFRAME src="http://www.xyz.com" 
            tal:attributes="src string:${here/absolute_url}/rfpreview"
            ondragstart="false" onselectstart="false"
            width="100%" height="400" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"></IFRAME>
```

Can someone guide me on the complete custom code snippet for custom view :atreal.richfile.preview.interfaces.ipreview-atreal.richfile.preview.viewlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TAL statements are *attributes* on existing tags. You *can* introduce dummy elements with the `tal:` namespace prefix, but the statements like `define` and `condition` need to expressed as attributes still.

Also, the default TALES expression type is path expressions, but you want to use python expressions. That's fine, but you need to specify them as such with the `python:` prefix.

Last but not least, don't use `global` unless you absolutely have to, which is really rarely. Defined names live in the scope of the XML element they are defined on, and don't need to live on outside of these.

Here is how I'd express the logic:

```xml
<tal:block define="ispdf python:here.absolute_url().endswith('.pdf')">

    <embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plug-in" 
         tal:condition="ispdf"
         tal:attributes="src string:${here/absolute_url}#" 
         draggable="false" onselectstart="false"  />

    <iframe src="http://www.xyz.com" 
         tal:condition="not:ispdf"
         tal:attributes="src string:${here/absolute_url}/rfpreview"
         ondragstart="false" onselectstart="false"
         width="100%" height="400" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"></iframe>

</tal:block>
```

This introduces a new `<tal:block>` element to define the `ispdf` boolean variable, determined by a python expression. Then the two variants are switched on or off by the `tal:condition` attributes on each element based on that value being `True` or `False`.

Comment: Bang on Thx a lot, But how do I disable the mouseover event in this window for the pdf preview which shows the icons for  printing and saving. I need this desperately. Thanx once again

Comment: @user956424: That's a separate question altogether, one I don't know the answer to. I generally avoid that stuff. :-P

Comment: @user956424: You may want to make that same edit in your question, I merely copied the `iframe` code from your post.